# CSS into nodejs file to render an image

Tags: javascript, css, node.js

I have two files. The first one is a simple server.js file and an index.css file. The content is just after :

```js
const http = require('http');
const express = require('express')
const mycss = require('./index.css');

const server = http.createServer(function(request, response){
    response.write("<h1>Le site de Maimu !</h1>");
    app.use('/static', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
    response.end();
})

server.listen(5500, function(){
console.log("my server started on port number 5500 !")
})
```

The CSS *index.css* is very simple :

```css
body {
    background-image: url("guejar.jpg")
}
```

...and still it start barking these crude words :

```
body {
     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '{'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1027:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1063:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/maimu/Documents/js/test-server.js:8:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1099:14)

Node.js v17.9.0
```

Answer (score 0):

`require` or `import` a file will treat it as a `js` [`module`](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html), and for sure this is a not valid `js` syntax.

If you want to get the content of the `CSS` file your need to [`read`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html) it.